# No WiFi networks listed on 19.04 with Intel Wifi Link 5350

Tags: networking, drivers, xubuntu, 19.04, iwlwifi

I updated my trusty ThinkPad X200 to Xubuntu 19.04 and now I cannot connect to my WiFi Network. WiFi works fine in 18.04.2 but in 19.04 I don't see any WiFi networks when I click the WifI icon. I ran `lshw -C network` in a terminal and I see it listed under `*-network UNCLAIMED`. Same issue happens when running regular Ubuntu 19.04. Ethernet works fine and I have it hooked up to that for now.

So far I've tried:

1. Checking if the WiFi switch is off, It's switched on.
2. Going to Additional Drivers tab in the Software & Updates program, no drivers were found.
3. Using the firmware found at the bottom of  [this](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-5000-ucode-8.83.5.1-1.tgz) page, Same results.

Some additional suggestions would be nice.

Edit: Results of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` as suggested by Chili555:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5350 AGN [Echo Peak] Network Connection [8086:423b]
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5350 AGN [Echo Peak] Network Connection [8086:1011]
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
04:00.0 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Turbo Memory Controller [8086:444e] (rev 11)
```

I also did some research and this appears to be caused by a bug in the version of the iwlwifi driver currently in 19.04, it's been fixed according to [this Git](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/iwlwifi-fixes.git) page but the updates have not been pushed to 19.04 yet I think. I'd update it myself but I don't have that kind of know how yet.

Edit 2: Results of `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[   10.091583] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 327 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c:918 iwl_pci_probe+0x172/0x1f0 [iwlwifi]
[   10.091584] Modules linked in: input_leds(+) irqbypass(+) iwlwifi(+) i2400m_usb(+) btusb thinkpad_acpi(+) btrtl btbcm i2400m btintel nvram wmi_bmof drm_kms_helper drm ledtrig_audio wimax serio_raw bluetooth snd_seq_device cfg80211 i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops snd_timer ecdh_generic mei_me mei snd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ahci libahci psmouse lpc_ich i2c_i801 e1000e wmi video
[   10.091621] RIP: 0010:iwl_pci_probe+0x172/0x1f0 [iwlwifi]
[   10.091685]  iwl_pci_register_driver+0x24/0x40 [iwlwifi]
[   10.091697]  iwl_drv_init+0x89/0x8b [iwlwifi]
[   10.091738] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -22
```

Edit 3: result of `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` after updating the kernel:

```
[   12.769208] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   12.813930] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.83.5.1 build 33692 op_mode iwldvm
[   12.880380] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   12.880383] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   12.880384] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   12.880386] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) WiMAX/WiFi Link 5350 AGN, REV=0x24
[   12.984017] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   13.943893] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wls1: renamed from wlan0
[   26.499270] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x1-0x0
[   26.654883] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x1-0x0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Done, with some added info as well.

Comment: Please run: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 432B` In my 19.04 installation, your device is covered. Also run: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Next, edit your question to add the results. Do you get the errors listed at the git?

Comment: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 432B` Didn't give any results but `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` did, updated with those results.

Comment: This is the exact error listed at the git. I'm studying the process to implement the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you try the latest mainline stable kernel from Ubuntu. Please check your architecture; i.e. 32- or 64-bit:

```
arch
```

Assumming that it is x86_64, that is, 64-bit, then download these files:

https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.1.6/linux-headers-5.1.6-050106_5.1.6-050106.201905311031_all.deb

https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.1.6/linux-headers-5.1.6-050106-generic_5.1.6-050106.201905311031_amd64.deb

https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.1.6/linux-image-unsigned-5.1.6-050106-generic_5.1.6-050106.201905311031_amd64.deb

https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.1.6/linux-modules-5.1.6-050106-generic_5.1.6-050106.201905311031_amd64.deb

By default, downloads go to your folder Downloads. Open a terminal and run:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

After installation completes, reboot and show us:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: This fixed the issue, thank you! I've still updated the question to show the results of sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl

Comment: Looks perfect. Glad it's working! Thanks, also, for proof-testing the solution. I'm certain that others will search for and benefit from it.